# JavaFX load text with more lines in to javafx container

Tags: file, javafx, containers

i wanna load text from an external text or xml file in to a javafx container.
i dont know which container i should use for this (textarea, with noneditable or label).
problem, the file have more than one lines to read.
For example:
File.txt contains:
"Hello

I'm the third row"

I actual use (for text-files) the normal BufferedReader-Code:
Possible1:

```
String text;
while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
   textlabel_about.setText(text);
}
```

or
Possible2:

```
textlabel_about.setText(ReadTextfile(file){
StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
String text;
while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      stringBuffer.append(text);
}
return stringBuffer.toString();
);
```

(Yes i cut the functions - of course i'm using exceptions and so on)
But if i run the program i only can see:
Possible1: "I'm the third row"
Possible2: "HelloI'm the third row"

I only know the function while using the console with system.out.println to get the diffrent lines. So what can i do to show the text in the javafx container in the right formation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BufferedReader.readLine` removes the line breaks. Just add the line breaks back in and use a `TextArea`:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String text;
while ((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(text).append("\n");
}
// set the text in the TextArea
your_text_area.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

A `TextArea` breaks lines that are too wide, but adds a ScrollBar if the content gets too high for the container (does not resize vertically normaly).

Alternatively you can to use `javafx.scene.text.Text`. `Text` resizes to the content size by default.

Comment: But how can i change the code of reading? is utf-8 default?
Getting Problems while using special signs like ä,ö,ü,ß and so on

Comment: @malex, Default charset is the default system charset. Try [Files.newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path, java.nio.charset.Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)